# Function giving warning saying no return values

Tags: vb.net

```
Function LoginPass() As Boolean
    Dim LogPass As New waxClass
    Dim Ldt As DataTable = LogPass.LoginPass(LCase(UserName_TextBox.Text),
                                             LCase(UserPass_TextBox.Text))
    If Ldt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        waxClass.LMUser = Ldt.Rows(0).Item("Username").ToString
        'Utility.LMUserID = Ldt.Rows(0).Item("UserID").ToString
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

When I try to use the above function it gives a warning saying:

> Function 'LoginPass' doesn't return a value on all code
>   paths. Are you missing a 'Return' statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function requires a `Boolean` return value.

You do not have a return value if `Ldt.Rows.Count <= 0`, so that is where the warning is coming from.  Add and `Else Return False` and you should be fine.

```
If Ldt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   waxClass.LMUser = Ldt.Rows(0).Item("Username").ToString
   'Utility.LMUserID = Ldt.Rows(0).Item("UserID").ToString
   Return True
Else
   Return False
End If
```